# Помогите с if, else. Не срабатывает сессия

Tags: php

Хай,
скажу сразу, я новичёк так скажем, и у меня возник вопрос.

```
<? if($isProf) { ?>

Показываем контакты

<? } else {?>

Не показываем контакты

<? }?>
```

Т.е если человек становится isPof он видит контакты, если нет, то не видит.
Вроде всё работает, но только если я перезахожу на сайт.

Покупаю PRO аккаунт, контакты не вижу, перезахожу - вижу.
Заканчивается PRO аккаунт, контакты виду, перезахожу - не вижу.

Как зставить работать If/else моментально?

С ув

Comment: @Васислий, а откуда вы этот самый `$isProf` берёте? Где он хранится, откуда тянется?

Comment: We need to go deeper. Откуда метод `getUserInfo` узнаёт, является ли пользоваткль `pro`? И каким образом статус пользователя меняется на `pro` и обратно?

Comment: @fori1ton, я и так скажу - из сессии берет. Нужно искать то место, где оно в сессию устанавливается, и ту проверку, что найдется, вкорячивать в isProf().

Comment: откуда у меня такое чувство что надо посмотреть как $isProf устанавливается, ведь в суперсекретном Файл.php описан класс... хотя не, всё понятно. вы при логине устанавливаете что-то типа $_SESSION['User'], и потом только туда и смОтрите, сделайте isProf методом, который опрашивает базу данных, или getUserInfo сделайте таким, чтобы только минуту были данные в сессии действительны, потом опрос базы.

Comment: @Васислий, нужно больше информации. Смотрите как у вас происходит логин, там как-то устанавливается сесссия, всё что  вы показали уже вторичный код, видимо на самописном(?) фреймворке, чтобы понять как вам помочь нам нужна либо документация к фреймворку, либо его куски.

Comment: @Василий, выложите проект на какой-нибудь гитхаб или (что хуже, но терпимо) обменник с паролем.

Comment: Добраться до своего гитхаба не могу сейчас, поэтому пока сделал так - http://files.mail.ru/89B0F5D7948947A5BC5F1AD900D0FA1F

1988qwerty password

Comment: после  покупки вызовите метод

    $this->security->expire();

но это только от юзера сработает.

ещё вариант в методе `setUserInfo()` в файле security.php поставить timestamp типа `$this->sessionData['timestamp']=time()` и где нибудь (например в методе checkExpired сравнивать time() и этот timestamp, вызывать $this->expire() если больше минуты. там была попытка сделать это, но видимо неудачная.

Comment: Спасибо большое, уже лучше.. не надо делать выход и вход занаво, а достаточно рефрешнуть страницу... осталось сделать, рефрешь принудительный :)))

Comment: да зачем обновлять, ткнут по ссылке, и оно скажет - низя, обновлять принудительно чтобы это надо пилить сервер событий, чтобы браузер все время опрашивал сервер, или был с ним на связи (не для php).

Comment: Подождите...
<? 
$this->security->expire();
if($isProf) { ?>

Показываем контакты

<? } else {?>

Не показываем контакты

<? }?>
купил PRO , сделал F5 - всё ок
снял PRO, сделал F5 - всё ок.

Т.е купив PRO, я делаю сам рефреш страницы, что-бы сработал If - else

Answer (score 1):

У Вас скорее всего $isProf берётся из сессии. Туда же нужно тогда положить и время окончания платного периода. Например timestamp. Ну и расширить проверку до

```
if($isProf && $_SESSION['end_paid_time'] > time())
```

Comment: хм, тоже верно.. спасибо!
однако , страницу нужно рефрнешнуть ф5, что-бы сработало

Comment: там прикол в том, что $_SESSION['end_paid_time'] и прочее только при expired устанавливается, а как оно окажется в сессии если сервер подтверждает оплату а не юзер :)