# Редирект после if?

Tags: php

Ссылаясь на вчерашнюю [тему](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/299709/php-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5-%D1%81-if-else-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D1%81%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82-%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%8F)
Я сделал вот так, всё работает... НО! для того, что-бы увидеть контакты, мне надо войти к себе в профиль и от туда снова к заказчику.
Как сделать редирект как только сработает isProf?

```
<? 
if($isPro or $isOwner)
{ 

$this->security->expire();

   ?>
 бла бла
    <? } ?>
  </ul>

  <?php } else {?> <!-- Если не аккаунт Про -->  

  бла бла бла

  <?php }?>  

  <?php } else {?> <!-- Если не залогинен -->

 бла бла бла
  <?php }?>
```

Comment: что значит "как только сработает" ? там isPro каждый раз вызывается.

Comment: хмм.. я уже запутался... дело в том, что данный функционал работает в том случае, если я купив Pro, зайду к себе в профиль, а от туда в профиль к заказчику. Т.е надо делать 2 действия. 
Т.е необходимо сделать редирект после покупки PRO в свой профиль...
я пытался через header location - никак, и делал ещё всякие разные способы никак.

Comment: Охх, уже функция, я уже пытался делать через подставную форму после покупки, но всёравно никаки :)))

Comment: Попробуйте это:

    sendHeader('Location', $URL);
$URL, это переменнаяс нужным вам адресом. Можно просто текст в кавычках написать, вместо переменной.

[Мануал](http://us2.php.net/manual/ru/function.header.php)